# how to remove password from seahorse/gnome-keyring forever

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome-keyring

I unlock my pc using hardware key+pin, instead of password. The drawback to that is, that keyring isn't opened by that so I'd have to enter the password, which kinda defies the purpose.

The solution is to disable the password in keyring and store passwords in plaintext. Not ideal, but drive is crypted, pc attended, location safe. So far so good.

But from time to time, I don't know why, the seahorse for whichever reason somehow remembers, that I should use the passwords and enable it again.

How to block it once for all? What to do so that I'm never asked for password again?